# Failed to load JVM library?

Tags: jvm, java

I am using a third party component which generates these entries in its log file:

```
2012/12/18 10:44:12 JVM loadlibrary: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
2012/12/18 10:44:12 load of JVM library failed
```

The above file path does exist.  This error does not occur when I have `Java 1.5` installed instead.

What could be the problem?

I have found that this error does not occur on some systems.

Comment: looks like the third party component is not compatible with JVM 1.6. Without knowing what exactly third party component is doing, its hard to point a definite answer.

Comment: Could it be something else, like permissions etc?

Comment: Probably not. You may try to install JVM on a path without spaces. What is the exact version of JVM you are using? Perhaps try with a later version.

Comment: check if there is an updated version of your 3rd party component

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: I have found that this error does not occur on some systems. Maybe it is something to do with how the JRE has been installed - registry settings?

Comment: Probably, probably not. Exactly why and how your third party component trying to load jvm like that.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: that is not something I have any control over.

Comment: Perhaps enable trace logging on 3rd party component? Another option is to enable remote debugging on your java process and then attach it to your favorite IDE to determine the stack trace and other related information. Lastly, try reverse engineer the 3rd component to figure out what exactly its trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to use a 64 bit Java with 32 bit DLL?

Comment: @mikeslattery: no, the JRE installation file is `jre-6u12-windows-i586-p.exe` so it `x86`.

Comment: do we have dirty java.exe under `C:\WINDOWS\system32` ?

Comment: i got this error when installing a 64-bit version of the JDK. Can you try with a 32-bit version instead.

Comment: @kshen: how would I find out that?

Comment: @CJ7, try command line `C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe -version` to show the output? In fact, I ever meet the similar "load of JVM library failed" issue for having installed a 64-bit JDK. To uninstall the 64-bit JDK or delete java.exe/javaw.exe under `C:\WINDOWS\system32` can work around for me. Not sure if that's the root cause for your problem.

Comment: @kshen: I get: `java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)` which is the version I expected.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: I have discovered that it is trying to find `msvcr71.dll` but fails to. I think this is an instance of http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6509291

Comment: @CJ7 did you try to install VC redistributable and see if it resolves the issue?

Comment: The solution is to have a copy of `msvcr71.dll` in `JAVA_HOME\bin\client\ ` or the app folder.